# Get the inspector list of elements

Tags: android, appium

I would like to know how to get the list of all the element visible in a page like into the inspector.

For example, in [this image](http://bitbar.com/wp-content/uploads/old_testdroid/2015/12/Screen-Shot-2015-12-08-at-13.30.08.png), we can see that the inspector lists all the element present into the page.

My question is: what is the command/class/method to get the same information?

Answer (score 0):

For Android you have to use the UIAutomatorViewer that is supplied with the Android SDK manager. It will be accessible once you install the SDK manager which can be downloaded from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html).

Another option is to use Chrome dev tools. Read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3).